# News cards with Bootstrap(caption, news, date and image)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make something like this, but nothing I do works. Basicly I put everything in one row and then use columns, but then text goes over the image. What is the best way to create something like this and for it to be responsive? On large screens, it looks like this, but on small screens, image goes over the text in 100% width. Im not asking for code, just for the tip. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: check out this link might give you some direction. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/Fatehi_Alqadasi/qsk511bp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some Bootstrap snippet sites for good approaches. I can recommend using [bootsnipp.com](http://bootsnipp.com). Someone posted a similar approach there, might be worth to give it a shot and adapt it to your concept: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/beautiful-image-card-with-description

Answer (score 0):

The mobile first approach would be defining the mobile state as default. Then define desktop in a media query. Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 newsitem">
      <img class="img-right" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&bg=0099ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Newsflash_500×700&w=500&h=700&fm=png" />
      <h1>About Me</h1>
      <p>Lots of text here...With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a .clearfix and o</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 newsitem">
      <img class="img-right" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&bg=0099ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Newsflash_500×700&w=500&h=700&fm=png" />
      <h1>About Me</h1>
      <p>Lots of text here...With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a .clearfix and o</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
.img-right {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
/*desktop*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .img-right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 10px;
  }
  .newsitem {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/sud17ec6/1/